# Understanding code executed after run command in Docker

Tags: docker

I just saw the below script in the Docker doc's.

```
$ docker restart db
db
$ docker run -t -i --rm --link db:db training/webapp /bin/bash
root@aed84ee21bde:/opt/webapp# cat /etc/hosts
172.17.0.7  aed84ee21bde
. . .
172.17.0.9  db
```

What is happening after the run cammand is executed ? , the below part i mean:

```
root@aed84ee21bde:/opt/webapp# cat /etc/hosts
```

Can somebody explain this line by line, I fail to understand. Please this is really important to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run -t -i --rm --link db:db training/webapp /bin/bash
```

This line executes the command `/bin/bash` in a container created from the image `training/webapp`.  `/bin/bash` is an interactive shell, and so executing it means that you're now in a shell inside the fake machine that is the Docker container.  `root@aed84ee21bde:/opt/webapp#` is the shell's prompt, indicating that you are `root` on host `aed84ee21bde` with current directory `/opt/webapp`.  `cat /etc/hosts` means the same thing here that it does outside the container, except that here it's referring to the `/etc/hosts` file inside the container, which is likely different from the one on your main system.